# Permission denied when attempting to ssh from remote server A to remote server B

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I'm attempting to copy a file from a remote server to another remote server. I've generated a public key from server A via `ssh-keygen -t rsa` and copied the contents of the public key to the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file in server B.

Yet, when I attempt to test the connection by ssh'ing into server B, I get a permission denied error. Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: I would first look at the permissions. Is `.ssh` 700? Are `.ssh/*` 600? On both sides?

Comment: And try ssh -vvv ... so you can see why it failed.

Comment: please provide the exact error you get and sshd configuration changes you made on server B.


`ssh-copy-id <server_B>` is simpler way to copy public keys

Comment: Try running ssh with the "-vvv" flag to make it print debugging information, then [edit] your question to include the debugging output. It would also be helpful to run "ls -la" on the .ssh directory of server B, then include that output in your question.

Comment: Please see updates above.

Comment: "Not sure why that worked though" – Because `~/.ssh/identity` is not among paths your local `ssh` checks by default to load a private key. Now you can [answer your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer); your "update" belongs to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by adding `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity` flag to the config file. As @Kamil mentioned, it's because `~/.ssh/identity` is not among the paths that the local `ssh` checks by default to load the private key. Explicitly adding `IdentityFile` allows ssh to check the specified path for the private key.

Answer (score 0):

#ssh-keygen

> (enter)

> (enter)

> (enter)

#ssh-copy-id -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@x.x.x.x (ip server B)

> 

for test: ssh root@x.x.x.x (ip server B)

---

*notice*
If server B has a non-default ssh port - put it in your command or change the ssh file

/etc/ssh/ssh_config

in line  41

Port 22

change it

Port X(portssh Server  B)

Comment: This does not address the problem that the identify file in question was not being searched.

Answer (score 0):

The default for SSH protocol version 1 is `~/.ssh/identity` (which is mostly unused now). For SSH version 2 `~/.ssh/id_rsa` is the typical path or symbolic link of the owner's private key file. That's why **id_rsa.pub** was mentioned in **ssh-copy-id** example above, because **ssh-keygen** proposes by default `~/.ssh/id_rsa` for private key and `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` for public key.